# titlesec and \section* in \titleformat

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, starred-version

I use `\titleformat` (`titlesec` package) to make some fancy headings in my documents. But I did not find a way to know, in the `\titleformat` specifications, if the section is made with a `\section` or a `\section*`.

Is there a way to detect that and make some test on it ?

What I want (a minimal example):

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{first}{label}{0pt}{\ifsectionstar{#1}{\bf #1}}[trailer]
```

Comment: Have you looked at section 3.8 of the manual?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define the titleformat for starred versions with the `numberless` key, i.e, like

```
\titleformat{\section}[block]           {first}{label}{0pt}{\textbf{#1}}[trailer] % all versions
\titleformat{\section}[block,numberless]{first}{label}{0pt}{#1}[trailer] % starred version
```

Comment: This syntax is deprecated. The syntax proposed in feklee's answer works.

Answer (score 13):

To format `\section*` use the `numberless` setting in the *extended syntax* for the first argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]{\bf}{label}{1em}{#1}[trailer]

\begin{document}
\section*{Foo}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\bf`? Rather it should be `\bfseries`, I'd guess.