# How to modifier chapter*?

Tags: formatting, chapters, titlesec

```
 \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
    \usepackage{graphicx, calc}
    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    %\usepackage{tocloft}

    \titleformat{\chapter}[block]
    {\bfseries\LARGE\filleft\sffamily}
    {\raisebox{ -1ex}{ \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}}\raisebox{ -5ex}{ \resizebox{1cm}{1.5cm}{\thechapter}}}{.5em}{\color{red}\titlerule[2pt]\\
    \vspace{-3ex}%
     \hspace{5cm} \filright  \begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}\bfseries\Huge\normalfont}
    [\end{minipage}]
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\vspace{1cm}\hfill Table of Contents}
    %\renewcommand\cftaftertoctitle{\hfill\par\vspace{1cm}}
    \begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \chapter{Préliminaire}
    jdjd
    \chapter{Éléments finies 1D}
    \chapter{Éléments finies 2D}

    \section{example}

    \lipsum[3]
    \chapter{Espace de SOBOLEV }
    \lipsum[3]
    \chapter*{Espace de SOBOLEV}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Why did you remove the image? Also, please be a bit more specific about what kind of modifications you want to make.

Comment: Use `\titleformat{\chapter,numberless}…` .

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102116)?