# How to change vertical spacing on frontmatter chapters

Tags: spacing, books, front-matter, vertical

I'm new to latex, and I'm writing a document (book), since vertical space above \chapter is to big I want to reduce it, for chapters in the mainmatter I have no problem, because I  use

```
\documentclass [12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\vskip40pt\raggedright}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}
\begin{document}    
 \frontmatter

 \tableofcontents
 \chapter{Abstract}
    this...
  \mainmatter
 \chapter{Introduction}
   work...
 \chapter{Results}
   good ones...
\end{document}
```

where the "-50pt" is my desired vertical space above chapter. The problem arises when I try to do the same on the frontmatter chapters (abstract, toc, dedication, etc), since the code above does not affect them. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your example compilable by adding the documentclass, the required packages and the document environment to your code, so that it reproduces your issue. That will help us help you.

Comment: Chapters in front matter is numberless. Take a look at this one may help! https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102116/titlesec-and-section-in-titleformat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the definition of `\tableofcontents` in standard class `book`

```
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
```

The table of contents' caption is printed by the stared version of `chapter` which has no **label** and **counter**. The `titlesec` package has `numberless` key for stared version **titles**.

```
\documentclass [12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\vskip40pt\raggedright}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\raggedright}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}
\begin{document}
 \frontmatter
 \tableofcontents
 \chapter{Abstract}
    this...
  \mainmatter
 \chapter{Introduction}
   work...
 \chapter{Results}
   good ones...
\end{document}
```