# How to create a command for the sections with an svg next to it on the top of the page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, positioning, draw

This is an addendum of a previous question: [How to place a `\draw` near the page number using `tikzpicture` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/529696/152550).

---

## What I want

I would like to have the section text moved to the top of every page, and place an image next to it. Look at this:

[image: What I want]

Why I mention sections? Because when the document is finished I want to make a ToC at the beginning.

- The image (`svg` file) is always the same.

For example:

- The full document has 8 pages in total.
- In page 1 there should be nothing.
- In pages 2-4, the green rectangle should have: `Section One: Text` with the image next to it.
- In pages 5-7, the green rectangle should have: `Section Two: More text` with the image next to it.
- In page 8, the green rectangle should have: `Bibliography` with the image next to it.

and we should be able to produce a ToC with those 3 sections (two sections and the bibliography).

## What I have done

Consider this MWE (taken from the accepted answer of the addendum):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newsavebox{\arrowL}
\newsavebox{\arrowR}
\sbox\arrowR{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=1mm,white,line cap=round,line join=round] 
(0,0) -- (7pt,8pt) -- (0pt,16pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\sbox\arrowL{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=1mm,white,line cap=round,line join=round] 
(0,0) -- (-7pt,8pt) -- (0pt,16pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{
%\newcommand{\sec}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
        \fill[green] (current page.north west) rectangle ++(\paperwidth,-1.5cm);%
        \node[text=white,anchor=west,xshift=4cm,yshift=-.75cm,font=\LARGE\bfseries] at (current page.north west) (a) {Section One: Text};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
%}
}
\rfoot{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \fill[black] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(\paperwidth,1.5cm)
        node[midway,align=center,font=\LARGE\bfseries,text=white,xscale=1.5] 
        (pageno-\number\value{page}) 
        {\thepage}; % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443744/152550
        \ifnum\value{page}<\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}
         \path ([xshift=\paperwidth/4]pageno-\number\value{page}) 
            node{\hyperlink{page.\the\numexpr\value{page}+1}{\usebox\arrowR}};
        \fi
        \ifnum\value{page}>1
         \path ([xshift=-\paperwidth/4]pageno-\number\value{page}) 
            node{\hyperlink{page.\the\numexpr\value{page}-1}{\usebox\arrowL}};
        \fi % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529698/152550
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

%\sec{Section One: Text}
\tikz\node[circle,draw,
           path picture={
               \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
                   \includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{Example.png}
               };
           }]{}; % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193558/152550

Example
\newpage 
Another example

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Problems:

- I don't know how to use `\newcommand[1]{\sec}{...}` to have different sections on pages, where the argument is the name of the section.
- The cropped image does not show on the 2.5cm circle (inside `\begin{document}`). (I have loaded `graphicx` and put `\graphicspath`. I tried with `\includegraphics{Example.png}` outside `tikzpicture` and it worked.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `titlesec`. That way you can use ordinary `\section` commands for that purpose. This has various advantages (table of contents, hyperlinks, ...). You then only need to type

```
\section{I am a cat}
Example
\newpage 
\section{You are a duck}
Another example
```

in the body of your document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newsavebox{\arrowL}
\newsavebox{\arrowR}
\sbox\arrowR{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=1mm,white,line cap=round,line join=round] 
(0,0) -- (7pt,8pt) -- (0pt,16pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\sbox\arrowL{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=1mm,white,line cap=round,line join=round] 
(0,0) -- (-7pt,8pt) -- (0pt,16pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\fancyhf{}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{}{}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \fill[green] (current page.north west) rectangle 
  ([yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north east);
 \node[text=white,anchor=west,font=\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily,anchor=west]  (a)
    at ([xshift=4cm,yshift=-.75cm]current page.north west)
   {Section \thesection: #1};
   \clip ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-.75cm]current page.north west)
    circle[radius=1.24cm];
   \node at 
   ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-.75cm]current page.north west)
    {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-duck}};
         \end{tikzpicture}
}[]

% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236778
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[display]{}{}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \fill[green] (current page.north west) rectangle 
  ([yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north east);
 \node[text=white,anchor=west,font=\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily,anchor=west]  (a)
    at ([xshift=4cm,yshift=-.75cm]current page.north west)
   {#1};
   \clip ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-.75cm]current page.north west)
    circle[radius=1.24cm];
   \node at 
   ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-.75cm]current page.north west)
    {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}[]


\rfoot{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \fill[black] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(\paperwidth,1.5cm)
        node[midway,align=center,font=\LARGE\bfseries,text=white,xscale=1.5] 
        (pageno-\number\value{page}) 
        {\thepage}; % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443744/152550
        \ifnum\value{page}<\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}
         \path ([xshift=\paperwidth/4]pageno-\number\value{page}) 
            node{\hyperlink{page.\the\numexpr\value{page}+1}{\usebox\arrowR}};
        \fi
        \ifnum\value{page}>1
         \path ([xshift=-\paperwidth/4]pageno-\number\value{page}) 
            node{\hyperlink{page.\the\numexpr\value{page}-1}{\usebox\arrowL}};
        \fi % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529698/152550
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section{I am a cat}
Example
\newpage 
\section{You are a duck}
Another example

\newpage 
\section*{Bibliography}
A book about ducks and seven books about marmots.

\end{document}
```

[image]

One can change the details of the implementation easily.

Comment: Of course one can adjust the details of the implementation in many ways.

Comment: Thanks! This answer contemplate the possibility of adding a section that has no number? For example, a section called `Bibliography`.

Comment: @manooooh Yes: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102120. You can define a format for a numberless section.

Comment: @manooooh I added an explicit example. (I am pretty sure one can tune things up, e.g. add the page break to the definition of section and so on. I will be offline now for a bit but happy to add things of that sort later, if needed.)